# Is it possible to change I/O priority in Windows server?

Tags: oracle11g

I have already changed the priority of all the processes of oracle  to high. It helped to improve the performance ; however, now I/O of my system is bottle neck for my database operation. So, Is it possible to change the I/O priority of oracle process from Normal to high?

Comment: Have you tuned your indexes/queries so they're efficient and don't do a lot of table scans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now I/O of my system is bottle neck
>   for my database operation. So, Is it
>   possible to change the I/O priority of
>   oracle process from Normal to high?

Reality check: think of what you want. Your request makes no sense.

IO is no something the CPU does. IO is something the DISCS do. If you overload the dics, then a higher CPU prority will not change the fact.

Get better / faster / more discs to give you a larger IOPS budget. Databases are notoriously hard on disc requirements.

Comment: Changing IO priority makes a lot of sense if you have a lot different processes doing I/O (not all OSs supports that though). But you're right, for a database server it's usually faster discs that will help you.

Comment: I want my system to have optimum utilization of resources. To give more time for the oracle process I have increase the process priority.
I have found that for  I/O intensive queries its I/O performance is quite good.
I am using oracle 11g and I have around 60 GBs of data in my database.  I have found that main memory uses remains the same of all the queries. So, I am curious to know if there is any way to optimize main memory utilization of oracle query.